# Index for CSS selector for multiple elements

Tags: html, selenium, css-selectors

I have following code. As you can see, all my `div` elements has same `class name`. I want to select 3rd `div` element by CSS selector. I couldn't find any way. `nth-child(n)` is used for sub-element(child). Any idea?

```
<div class="linkDisplayStyle"> <a href="#1"> </div>
<div class="linkDisplayStyle"> <a href="#2"> </div>
<div class="linkDisplayStyle"> <a href="#3"> </div>
<div class="linkDisplayStyle"> <a href="#4"> </div>
<div class="linkDisplayStyle"> <a href="#5"> </div>
<div class="linkDisplayStyle"> <a href="#6"> </div>
```

Comment: Each element within the html document except the html element itself has a parent node.

Comment: `By.cssSelector(".linkDisplayStyle:nth-of-type(2)")` should help you. nth-of-type is a 0 based index so giving in 2 would return the 3rd element.

Answer (score 3):

`nth-child` works when you look for child under a parent node. To show you an example I came up with the following

```
.parent>div:nth-child(3)
```

**Html**

```
<div class="parent"> 
    <div class="linkDisplayStyle"> <a href="#1"> </div>
    <div class="linkDisplayStyle"> <a href="#2"> </div>
    <div class="linkDisplayStyle"> <a href="#3"> </div>
    <div class="linkDisplayStyle"> <a href="#4"> </div>
    <div class="linkDisplayStyle"> <a href="#5"> </div>
    <div class="linkDisplayStyle"> <a href="#6"> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nth-child(3)` to select 3rd element. You can also use `nth-of-type(3)`.

```css
.linkDisplayStyle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: red;
  float: left;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
}
.linkDisplayStyle:nth-of-type(3) {
  background: green;
}
.linkDisplayStyle a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="linkDisplayStyle">
  <a href="#1">1</a>
</div>
<div class="linkDisplayStyle">
  <a href="#2">2</a>
</div>
<div class="linkDisplayStyle">
  <a href="#3">3</a>
</div>
<div class="linkDisplayStyle">
  <a href="#4">4</a>
</div>
<div class="linkDisplayStyle">
  <a href="#5">5</a>
</div>
<div class="linkDisplayStyle">
  <a href="#6">6</a>
</div>
```